# HTML Multiple Tasks of Code Written on a single Line

Tags: php, html

I am webscraping HTML code into R and one of the issues I am encountering is that sometimes many tasks of HTML code are written on a single line as below.

I am trying to parse out lines so that its neat and all the tasks are formatted line-by-line as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Document created using Wdesk 1 -->
        <!-- Copyright 2018 Workiva -->
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;">

    <div> Stuff_1 info in here </div></div> <div> Stuff_2 info in here </div></div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

to this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Document created using Wdesk 1 -->
        <!-- Copyright 2018 Workiva -->
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;">

    <div> Stuff_1 info in here </div></div> 
    <div> Stuff_2 info in here </div></div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

How do I parse out multiple tasks HTML of code, written on a single line? Thank you.

Comment: first let me say that html isn't "code", it's markup. second how (and what for) do you "parse out lines" (for what kind of output?). There's a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse and work with html documents.

Comment: By task do you mean`tag`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/Paste your HTML to [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) then click on `FORMAT HTML`.

If your question concerns a particular language, please edit your question for more information.

---

**Edit:** In PHP, you can take a look at [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php).

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I did that, though it still did not separate the several HTML tasks on the same line into two different lines.

Comment: Thank you so much I tried it again and it worked this time! Can I ask your expertise for another quick question? How about HTML tasks where the task is split (does not continue on the same line). Is there a way to combine the HTML task into a single line?

Comment: Line (1) <div> Stuff info                                                                                                 in here </div></div>

Comment: Line (1) <div> Stuff info ...                                                                                                 Line (2) in here </div></div>